# Algorithm for seeing if many different arrays are subsets of another one?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, language-agnostic, subset

Let's say I have an array of ~20-100 integers, for example `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` (actually numbers more like `[106511349 , 173316561, ...]`, all nonnegative 64-bit integers under 2^63, but for demonstration purposes let's use these).

And many (~50,000) smaller arrays of usually 1-20 terms to match or not match:

```
1=[2, 3, 8, 20]
2=[2, 3, NOT 8]
3=[2, 8, NOT 16]
4=[2, 8, NOT 16] (there will be duplicates with different list IDs)
```

I need to find which of these are subsets of the array being tested. A matching list must have all of the positive matches, and none of the negative ones. So for this small example, I would need to get back something like `[3, 4]`. List 1 fails to match because it requires 20, and list 2 fails to match because it has NOT 8. The NOT can easily be represented by using the high bit/making the number negative in those cases.

I need to do this quickly up to 10,000 times per second . The small arrays are "fixed" (they change infrequently, like once every few seconds), while the large array is done per data item to be scanned (so 10,000 different large arrays per second).

This has become a bit of a bottleneck, so I'm looking into ways to optimize it.

I'm not sure the best data structures or ways to represent this. One solution would be to turn it around and see what small lists we even need to consider:

```
2=[1, 2, 3, 4]
3=[1, 2]
8=[1, 2, 3, 4]
16=[3, 4]
20=[1]
```

Then we'd build up a list of lists to check, and do the full subset matching on these. However, certain terms (often the more frequent ones) are going to end up in many of the lists, so there's not much of an actual win here.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a better algorithm for solving this sort of problem?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to make a tree with the smaller arrays since they change less frequently, such that each subtree tries to halve the number of small arrays left.

For example, do frequency analysis on numbers in the smaller arrays. Find which number is found in closest to half of the smaller arrays. Make that the first check in the tree. In your example that would be '3' since it occurs in half the small arrays. Now that's the head node in the tree. Now put all the small lists that contain 3 to the left subtree and all the other lists to the right subtree. Now repeat this process recursively on each subtree. Then when a large array comes in, reverse index it, and then traverse the subtree to get the lists.

Comment: Building a tree makes sense, but I think it would need to be a ternary tree: one subtree will contain arrays that specify `3`, one subtree will contain arrays that specify `NOT 3`, and one subtree will contain arrays that don't specify either. At each branch, you need to descend into two of the three subtrees. The optimal tree structure would probably be the one where the not-specify-either subtree is smallest, since that's the subtree that you have to descend into unconditionally.

Comment: the "not 3" could also be a separate node to the "3" node.

Comment: True, but my main point is that you will *always* recurse into the "doesn't require this" subtree; so your goal that "each subtree tries to halve the number of small arrays left" is not ideal. Instead, your goal should be to choose conditions that, if not met, eliminate as many of the small arrays as possible.

Comment: good point, multiple branches. I guess there are various tests that can be used on the small arrays. So a greedy algorithm of "given a list of small arrays, which test can most likely split the number of small arrays we have to continue to look at in half", that keeps splitting, making a tree with groups of small arrays, is probably fairly good bang for buck in terms of being easy to code & reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state which of your arrays are sorted - if any.

Since your data is not that big, I would use a hash-map to store the entries of the source set (the one with ~20-100 integers). That would basically let you test if a integer is present in O(1).

Then, given that 50,000(arrays) * 20(terms each) * 8(bytes per term) = 8 megabytes + (hash map overhead), does not seem large either for most systems, I would use another hash-map to store tested arrays. This way you don't have to re-test duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this may be less satisfying from a CS point of view, but if you're doing a huge number of tiny tasks that don't affect each other, you might want to consider parallelizing them (multithreading). 10,000 tasks per second, comparing a different array in each task, should fit the bill; you don't give any details about what else you're doing (e.g., where all these arrays are coming from), but it's conceivable that multithreading could improve your throughput by a large factor.

Answer (score 0):

First, do what you were suggesting; make a hashmap from input integer to the IDs of the filter arrays it exists in.  That lets you say "input #27 is in these 400 filters", and toss those 400 into a sorted set.  You've then gotta do an intersection of the sorted sets for each one.

Optional: make a second hashmap from each input integer to it's frequency in the set of filters.  When an input comes in, sort it using the second hashmap.  Then take the least common input integer and start with it, so you have less overall work to do on each step.  Also compute the frequencies for the "not" cases, so you basically get the most bang for your buck on each step.

Finally: this could be pretty easily made into a parallel programming problem; if it's not fast enough on one machine, it seems you could put more machines on it pretty easily, if whatever it's returning is useful enough.